# How and when does QGIS tile data when WMTS is checked in the QGIS server properties

Tags: qgis-3, wmts, qgis-server, server

There is a [WMTS section](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/services.html#web-map-tile-service-wmts) in the [QGIS server](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/server_manual/index.html) menu from the project properties:

[image: WMTS capabilities - QGIS server]

as far as I know, tiling large data to comply with the [WMTS](https://www.ogc.org/standards/wmts) standard, e.g. from a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database, can take quite some time (many hours), so how exactly does [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) deal with that, because I don't feel it's actually doing any kind of time-consuming tiling operations?

---

Version info: QGIS: 3.16 / Ubuntu: 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Could be wrong but I think you are mixing two things:

- WMTS can be considered as cutting a WMS image using a tiling grid for different levels/scales (see WMTS code in QGIS https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/server/services/wmts/qgswmtsgettile.cpp#L34). It's not really heavy and can be done on the fly (faster with a database as you have indexes to avoid consuming large chunks of memory)
- seeding: it's the fact to run a task to pregenerate a cache to avoid create WMTS image cache on the fly. It's what is time consuming (hours/days) as you generate thousands/millions of small map images. For QGIS, you need to install a QGIS Server plugin like https://github.com/3liz/qgis-server-wmts-cache-plugin for this intend